# QTreeView and QTabWidget to display only selected items of QTableViews

Tags: c++, sql, qt, model-view

Given two SQLite tables **addresses** and **messages**, what is the best way to map them to a `QTreeView` and `QTabWidget` in such a way, that if I select one row in a `QTableView` (which is either mapped to addresses or messages), the selected item is

1. opened as a new tab to display its contents, and
2. inserted as an item in the `QTreeView` to represent an "opened" item.

I've managed to open new tabs by creating two custom `QWidgets`, one for addresses and one for messages. On selecting a row in the `QTableView`, the correct (either addresses or messages) `QWidget` is created and fed with the SQL model and the index. The widget then creates a `QDataWidgetMapper` and displays the given index. `AddressWidget` example:

```
AddressWidget::AddressWidget(QSqlRelationalTableModel *model, QModelIndex &index, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    // ...

    // set up widget mapper
    mapper = new QDataWidgetMapper(this);
    mapper->setModel(this->model);
    mapper->addMapping(streetEdit, this->model->fieldIndex("street"));
    mapper->addMapping(houseNumberEdit, this->model->fieldIndex("houseNumber"));
    mapper->addMapping(zipEdit, this->model->fieldIndex("zip"));
    mapper->addMapping(cityEdit, this->model->fieldIndex("city"));
    mapper->setCurrentModelIndex(index);
}
```

How can I extend this to the `QTreeView`, so that the tree displays opened items? Each tab in the `QTabWidget` should have a corresponding item in the `QTreeView`.

If there is a *right* way of doing this, please add it or replace my scenario entirely.